# Data está vindo em formato errado

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Numa função jquery, eu recebo uma data na minha View. Acontece que a data está vindo assim:

```
/Date(1402369200000)/
```

Sei que preciso fazer um cast ou algo parecido, mas não sei como fazer. Alguém pode me dar um help?
Minha controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult MontaAgendamento(Agendamentos _agendamento)
        {
            V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();

            var agendamento = (
                             from pdv in db.T_PDV
                             from tarefa in db.T_TarefaParceiro.Where(trf => trf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from parceiro in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf => prf.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
                             from acao in db.T_Acao.Where(ac => ac.IDAcao == tarefa.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from proxima in db.T_ProximaAcao.Where(pxm => pxm.IDAcao == acao.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from info in db.T_InfoClientePdv.Where(inf => inf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from cliente in db.T_Cliente.Where(clie => clie.IDCliente == info.IDCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()

                             where pdv.CNPJ == _agendamento.Cnpj

                             orderby parceiro.DataVisita descending

                             select new
                             {
                                 pdv.CNPJ,
                                 pdv.DataCadastro,
                                 cliente.RazaoSocial,
                                 acao.Acao,
                                 proxima.ProximaAcao,
                                 parceiro.IDOsParceiro,
                                 parceiro.NumOs,
                                 parceiro.DataVisita,
                                 parceiro.DataAgendamento,
                                 parceiro.Tecnico
                             }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(new { agendamento }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Minha jquery:

```
function MontaAgendamento() {

    var str = "";
    var resultado = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "Cnpj": "' + $("#txtCNPJ").val() + '" , "Os": "' + $("#txtOS").val() + '" , "Acao": "' + $("#txtAcao").val()
                                        + '" , "ProximaAcao": "' + $("#txtProxAcao").val() + '" , "DataCadastro": "' + $("#txtDataCadastro").val() + '" }');

    var _agenda = $('#txtCNPJ').val() + $("#txtOS").val();

    $.ajax({

        url: '/GerenciarPDV/MontaAgendamento',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _agendamento: resultado}),
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.agendamento.Acao);

            str += '<div id="FiltroPesquisa">';

            str += '<div id="painelAcao">';
            str += '<table style="width: 100%;border-top: 1px solid black;">';
            str += '<tr>';
            str += '<td></td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '</table>';
            str += '<table style="width: 100%;">';
            str += '<tr>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">';
            str += '<label id="lblProxAcao">Ação</label></td>';
            str += '<td class="auto-style9">';
            str += '<input id="txtAcao" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.Acao + '" /></td>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">Próxima Ação</td>';
            str += '<td>';
            str += '<input id="txtProxAcao" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.ProximaAcao + '" /></td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '<tr>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">';
            str += '<label id="lblDTCadastro">Data Cadastro</label></td>';
            str += '<td class="auto-style24">';
            str += '<input id="txtDataCadastro" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.DataCadastro + '" /></td>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">';

            str += '<label id="lblIDV99">ID V99:</label></td>';
            str += '<td class="auto-style5">';
            str += '<input id="txtIDV99" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.IDOsParceiro + '"/></td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '<tr>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">';
            str += '<label id="lblDTAgendamento">Data Agendamento</label></td>';
            str += '<td class="auto-style9">';
            str += '<input id="txtDataAgenda" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.DataAgendamento + '"/></td>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel">';
            str += '<label id="lblTipoVisita">Tipo de Visita</label></td>';
            str += '<td>';
            str += '<input id="txtTipoVisita" type="text" readonly="true" value="' +  + '"/></td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '<tr>';
            str += '<td class="Formatlabel" style="width: 141px; font-weight: 700;">Data Visita</td>';
            str += '<td class="auto-style9">';
            str += '<input id="txtDataVisita" type="text" readonly="true" value="' + data.agendamento.DataVisita + '"/></td>';
            str += '<td  style="width: 110px;">';
            str += '</td>';
            str += '<td>';
            str += '&nbsp;</td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '</table>';
            str += '</div>';
.................................
$('#filtro').html(str);
            str = "";
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O valor `/Date(1402369200000)/` está no formato (unix) epoch (veja no wikipedia).

Para converter para Date em javascript use:

```
var x = new Date(1402369200000);
console.log(x);

// output: Tue Jun 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Você também pode utilizar uma lib que é muito útil para javascript:
http://momentjs.com/

Mais informações:
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Não consegui converter, devido ao /Date e / no final. Como eu faço para um new Date(meu_campo) sem que venha esses caracteres que invalidam a construção da data

Comment: Nesse caso, é comum o replace das informações indesejadas. Veja mais detalhes aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: Aconselho fortemente vc a utilizar o moment.js. Se vc está trabalhando com datas em JavaScript e precisa formatá-las, essa é a melhor lib que utilizei.